# Change button onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, django

In html, I have a button that shows text and a button to hide it. Each button have 'onclick' attribute that direct to a specific function in js. I want to change the 'onclick' value while clicking the button and also to change the text inside the button (show/hide).
I couldn't use 'triggleClass' because I need to use the 'onclick' attribute (It value changed because I'm using django) 
Currently, I have two buttons for this actions and I just want to unite both of them to one button.
Code:

```
<btn id="show_btn_{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="Show({{forloop.counter}})" class="btn show_btn">Show</btn>
<btn id="hide_btn_{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="Hide({{forloop.counter}})" class="btn hide_btn">Hide</btn>

<script>
function Show(pos){

    $('#show_text_'+pos).css('display','block');
    $('#my_text_show_btn_'+pos).prop("disabled", true);

}

function Hide(pos){
    $('#show_text_'+pos).css('display','none');
    $('#my_text_show_btn_'+pos).prop("disabled", false);

}
</script>
```

Does someone have a solution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<btn id="show_btn_{{forloop.counter}}" onclick="ShowHide({{forloop.counter}})" class="btn show_btn">Show</btn>

<script>
function ShowHide(pos){

    if ($('#show_text_'+pos).css('display') !== 'none') { //lets hide
        $('#show_text_'+pos).css('display','none');
        $('#show_btn_'+pos).html("Show");
    } else {
        $('#show_text_'+pos).css('display','block'); 
        $('#show_btn_'+pos).html("Hide");
    }

}

</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this short code:**

```js
function ShowHide(id) {
  if ($(id).html() == "Show") {
    $(id).html("Hide");
  } else {
    $(id).html("Show");
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<btn onclick="ShowHide(this);" class="btn show_btn">Show</btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show_btn').click(function(){
    if($(this).text()=='Show'){
        $(this).text('Hide');
     }
     else if($(this).text()=='Hide'){
        $(this).text('Show');
     }
   });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button  class="btn show_btn" data-attr='Hide'>Show</button>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){
   $('.show_btn').click(function(){
       var attr =$(this).attr('data-attr');
       var text =$(this).text();
       $(this).text( attr );
       $(this).attr('data-attr', text );
   });
});
</script>
```